# Swift 3 Segue in UITableViewCell Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, segue

I configure dynamic cells in a table using a UITableViewCell controller and I want to perform a segue when a particular tap gesture is clicked

```
class PostCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var actionComments: UIImageView!

    var post: FeedPost!

    let postID: String = ""

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(likeTapped))
        tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1

        actionLike.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        actionLike.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        let commentGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(goToComments))
        commentGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        commentGesture.delegate = self

        actionComments.addGestureRecognizer(commentGesture)
        actionComments.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    }

    func goToComments(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {



    }
}
```

this is my PostCell class (there is extra code i have just removed for sake of this post) and this is my tableview which is my newsfeedvc

```
class NewsFeedVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var posts = [FeedPost]()

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let post = posts[indexPath.row]

        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell") as? PostCell {

            cell.configureCell(post: post)

            return cell

        } else {

            return PostCell()

        }

    }

}
```

i have set the segue up with identifer but i cannot use the performsegue in the goToComments function in my postcell class?

Comment: What is stopping you using `performSegue` in `goToComments(sender:)`? Have you added the segue in the Storyboard? Does the app crash? What error message do you get? Some more detail is needed for people to understand the problem.

Comment: @RoboticCat if i add `performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToComments", sender: nil)` to the goToComments i get `Use on unresolved identifier`

Comment: What unresolved identifier - you're missing part of the error message which should indicate what is not in-scope. This should all be added to your question. Also, have you searched Stack Overflow for questions with the same error message? There are many solutions; what have you ruled out?

Comment: @RoboticCat 'performSegue' is the unresolved identifier. i have tried searching for solutions and they included overriding the prepare for segue however, the image that i am trying to add the gesture to is linked up to the `postcell: uitableviewcell` class so i cant declare it again in newsfeedvc in order to perform the segue there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem you have two options.

1. Create one `delegate/protocol` and implement it with `NewsFeedVC` and create instance of in inside the `PostCell`. After that set that `delegate` in `cellForRowAt` method now in `goToComments` use that delegate and call its method that you have implement in `NewsFeedVC` and inside that method perform the segue.
2. Instead of adding gesture in `awakeFromNib` method add it in the `cellForRowAt` method show you have its action method inside your `NewsFeedVC`. Now you can easily perform your segue.

Comment: i cant add the image to the newsfeedvc as an iboutlet in order to add the gesture at cellForRowAt?

Comment: @Chad Don't get your above comment, can you explain a bit more about your issue.

Comment: so i was attempting your second solution by adding the gesture in the cellforRowAt but this is in my `NewsFeedVC` whereas the awakeFromNib is part of the `PostCell: UITableViewCell` class and if i try to add the image view into the `NewsFeedVC` in order to add the gesture, i get an error `The outlet is invalid. The outlet cannot be connected to repeating data`

Comment: sorted it just as i posted that i understood what you really meant :)